# Using axis units (axis cs) for line width

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Say my plot shows geometric objects in a metric x,y plane, so one axis unit equals 1m. Drawing in metric units is easy using `axis cs` for the coordinates like in this example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,
            xmax=20,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=20,
            axis lines=center,
            axis equal
            ]
            \draw[line width=10mm] (axis cs: 10,0) -- (axis cs: 10,10);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way to define the **width** of the line in axis coordinate units also (maybe with veclen or so)?
`\draw[line width=10mm]` seems to define the width in the document target unit, `\draw[line width=10]` in some kind of pixel unit.

Comment: what do you mean by an axis coordinate unit? could you please clarify? Cant you use `10pt` instead?

Comment: @Raaja As described in the question, my axis unit represents meters (one step along an axis equals 1 meter). Now I want my line to have a width of 10 meters, or 10 axis units respectively. `10pt` yields the same result as `10`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. (In sufficiently recent versions of pgfplots `axis cs:` is no longer needed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,
            xmax=20,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=20,
            axis lines=center,
            axis equal
            ]
            \draw let \p1=($(axis cs: 1,0)-(axis cs: 0,0)$) in 
            % \x1 is now one axis x unit
            [line width=2*\x1] (axis cs: 10,0) -- (axis cs: 10,10);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works (in my example `line width=10*\x1` produces the desired line with line width 10 meters)!